# How to remove particular attribute from JSON string using C#

Tags: c#, json

I have `JSON` string as below

```
[{
        "attachments": [{ "comment": "communication", "comment_date_time": "2035826"} ], 
        "spent_hours": "4.00", 
        "description": ""       
    }, 
   {
        "attachments": [], 
        "spent_hours": "4.00", 
        "description": ""       
    }]
```

How can i remove the `attachments` attribute from the `JSON` string using C#.  I am using JSON.net.

Comment: try to use Newtonsoft.JSON to convert JSON to .Net objects and then you can remove it easily

Comment: try this => http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx

Comment: I think you can do like described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/32153051

Answer (score 22):

Using Linq

```
var jArr =  JArray.Parse(json);

jArr.Descendants().OfType<JProperty>()
                  .Where(p => p.Name == "attachments")
                  .ToList()
                  .ForEach(att=>att.Remove());

var newJson = jArr.ToString();
```

or using anonymous classes

```
var anon = new[] { new{spent_hours="", description=""} };
var newJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
                         JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(json, anon));
```