Model Creation for Dynamic property in C#
Existing data:
existing = {
    "MediaLRN" :'2',
  "Media":'a.2',
  "CultureDetails":{
     "24 Hrs": [
          {
              "Organism": "15",
              "Quantity": 2            
          },
          {
              "Organism": "36",
              "Quantity": 27
          }
      ],
       "48 Hrs": [
          {
              "Organism": "16",
              "Quantity": 3            
          },
          {
              "Organism": "56",
              "Quantity": 29
          }
      ],
  }
  };

model
public class MediaOutput
    {
        public string MediaLRN { get; set; }
        public string Media { get; set; }
     
        public Dictionary<string, List<OrganismDetail>> CultureDetails { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, List<OrganismDetail>>();
    }
 
      public class OrganismDetail
    {
        public string Organism { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }

Inside CultureDetails property name '24 Hrs', '48 Hrs' is dynamic word, like this , '72 Hrs','96 Hrs' can come.
Now, I want to remove the CultureDetails, need to change the data structure like this
new = {
  "MediaLRN " :'2',
"Media ":'a.2',
   "24 Hrs": [
        {
            "Organism": "15",
            "Quantity": 2            
        },
        {
            "Organism": "36",
            "Quantity": 27
        }
    ],
     "48 Hrs": [
        {
            "Organism": "16",
            "Quantity": 3            
        },
        {
            "Organism": "56",
            "Quantity": 29
        }
    ]
}

I don't know how to create a model for this in C#. could someone help on this ?

That's json, so this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32153010/remove-properties-from-a-json-string-using-newtonsoft
